# Android Play Asset Delivery: How to reuse old asset packs?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have a question about the google play asset delivery system.
Is it possible to reuse asset packs in previous versions of an app without redownloading them on the user end?

Right now, I have one asset pack which is currently in use, and I would like to add a second asset pack with some new images. I made no changes to the first asset pack (and never plan to), but when I go to download the app on internal testing, I get an update download with the size of ~300mb (which is the size of the 1st asset pack + the new one).

I read on [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery) that updating an app would invalidate all previously installed asset packs (which I am guessing causes the play store to download the 1st asset pack again), so I was wondering if there was a way around this, because I would really like to not re-download 300mb of cards when I only made a 13mb addition.

The app had already been installed, and the asset pack had also been fully downloaded and installed, so I was wondering why the update redownloaded it instead of leaving it alone.

I thought that putting the new images in a new asset pack would prevent the 1st pack from being invalidated, but it doesn't seem like that is working.

Basically, the end result I'm looking for is to have a ~15mb update which adds the new images and updates the base code (which is around 2mb total). Is this possible?

Here is the build.gradle of the 1st asset pack in case it helps:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.asset-pack'

assetPack{
    packName = "cards1_0"
    dynamicDelivery {
        deliveryType = "on-demand"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or if I'm completely wrong on this issue then I'd love to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have spent several hours trying to figure out the same thing.

What the documentation for Google Play Asset Delivery does not specify is that once you upload your bundle, it takes time to generate all the different APKs that users can download.

One of the first APKs that is generated is the one that downloads everything and is available right after you publish your internal update.

My download size was over 300 MB at first and included everything. However once I waited about 15-20 minutes, the download size went down to under 15 MB (as expected) on all my test devices.

So the answer is - wait until Google servers are done processing your bundle and generating delta packages in the background. The time will almost guaranteed vary depending on server load and your original bundle size.

Comment: Thanks man! I needed to wait about 45 minutes, and then it worked. :)